# Add class to table row clicked on

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where I display callback results in a table.

I'm trying to figure out how to highlight a row that I click on when I display details for that record.

I thought it might be possible using the $event method and applying a class change based on a property returned there.

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ngClass directive on the row to set a class depending upon the value of a scope variable.  Then use ngClick on the row to set the value of that scope variable.

`<tr ng-class="{'highlight':activeRow===0 }" ng-click="rowClick(0)">`

[I have created a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/WayneA/6ajdsoo6/)